# bal-util grunt with docpad

Tags: gruntjs, docpad

I have some trouble with the spawn function in bal-util. I tried [this example](https://gist.github.com/balupton/3898915) and the extended version from [this docpad skeleton](https://github.com/lukekarrys/html5-boilerplate.docpad), but I get the same error every time:

`error: An error occured:
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
    → [2013-06-01 14:03:27.698] [C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docpad\out\lib\docpad.js] [DocPad.log]`

I have the grunt-cli installed.

I use the following versions:

grunt - 0.4.1

bal-util - 2.1.0

**How could I fix it, to run grunt properly?**

Answer (score 2):

That example uses an older version of Grunt, 0.3.17. In order to use with the latest version of Grunt, 0.4.1, it looks like you'll need to do the following:

1. Rename `grunt.js` to `Gruntfile.js`.
2. `npm install grunt-cli grunt --save-dev`
3. Change `grunt.registerTask('default', Object.keys(gruntConfig).join(' '));` to  `grunt.registerTask('default', Object.keys(gruntConfig));`

...and probably more stuff.

Typically you install `npm install grunt-cli -g` globally to access the `grunt` command. Since that example has docpad spawning grunt locally, step 2 has you install both locally placing the `grunt` command at `node_modules/.bin/grunt`.

I recommend reading up on the DocPad and Grunt docs. Also a shameless plug to one of my own modules for using DocPad with Grunt: https://github.com/shama/grunt-docs and an example Gruntfile.js that uses it: https://github.com/shama/dontkry.com/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fixed my problem. I still can not run grunt, because it keeps returning with "exited with a non-zero status code".

Comment: the issue is not solved, but this is definitely a step in the right direction. I'll post the fix here once i find it